# Multiple when/then with where for each other

Tags: grails, testing, spock

I'm trying to write functional test with **Spock** and **Geb**. 
I want to use in one test method **multiple blocks of when/then** with **where** for each block. Is it possible? Or I should use one where for all the when/then?

Comment: What is your experience on each approach? Do you face any problem using either of them?

Comment: @dmahapatro, I'm trying to simulate user's behavior with test: 
click to edit button, fill fields, click save and etc. 
I'm newbie in spock and functional. I do something wrong? Thanks, dmahapatro

Comment: A common way to test a workflow is to have a separate method for each step. Then you can have one when-then-where in each method. To use this style of testing, annotate the test class with `@Stepwise`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, thanks, I will rework my test with this style.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will not be able to use `where` per interaction, it would complain about the usage. You would end up with a single `where` for multiple interactions. Follow [this as a sample](http://meetspock.appspot.com/script/98001):

```
def test() {
  given:   
  def c
  def d

  when:
  c = a + b

  then:
  c == result

  when:
  d = e - f

  then:
  d == res

  where:
  a | b |result | e |f |res
  1 | 2 | 3     | 7 |5 |2
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple interactions to test, then yes you can very well do that in one method. Follow [docs](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#scope-of-interactions) for details. @baxxabit

Comment: Thank you! One small question. In an example you use one where block for every when/then. If I define variable like 'name' in where, it will be available in every when block?

Comment: Please, answer on my second comment :)

Comment: I am not sure which example you are referring to. But yes from the sample mentioned in the answer above, you can refer a variable inside data grid of `where` block like 'name' in every when block. @baxxabit